# Does ZRANGEBYLEX support contains query?

Tags: redis

How can I query my sorted set to get all keys containing some characters?

"Starts with" works fine but I need "contains".
I am using below query for "start with" which works fine

```
zrangebylex zset [2110 "[2110\xff" LIMIT 0 10
```

Is there any way we can do \xff query \xff ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The lexicographical range for Redis' Sorted Sets can only be used for prefix searches.

Note that by using another Sorted Set that stores the reverse of the values you can also perform a suffix search on the values. However, even combining these two approaches will not provide the functionality you need.

Alternatively, you could perform a prefix search and then filter the results using a Lua script. Depending on your queries and data, this may or may not be an effective approach.

You could, also, consider implementing a full text indexing mechanism on top of Redis but that would be an overkill in most cases and besides, there are existing tested technologies that already do that.

Answer (score 1):

But you can use [ZSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) with a glob-style pattern, for example to get all the strings which contains the characters "*s*" and/or "*a*":

```
ZSCAN key 0 MATCH *[sa]*
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [ZRANGEBYLEX](http://redis.io/commands/ZRANGEBYLEX) original documentation (also look `zzlCompareElements` function realization in [source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_zset.c)):

> The elements are considered to be ordered from lower to higher strings as compared byte-by-byte using the memcmp() C function. Longer strings are considered greater than shorter strings if the common part is identical.

From memcmp [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/):

> `memcmp` compares the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by ptr1 to the first num bytes pointed by ptr2, returning zero if they all match or a value different from zero representing which is greater if they do not.

So you cant use `zrangebylex` with **contains** query. And I'm afraid there is not any "lite" workaround. "Lite" - without redis sourfce patching.

Comment: Thanks Misterion ! Problem is i am not finding any query to do that using ZRangeByLex